# Bounty question stuck in "Featured" tab for more than two weeks now

Tags: bug

Why is this question still showing up in the "Featured" tab? It was last edited on Jul 31, over two weeks ago.

[Carb. Rebuild or Adjustment?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/33586/675)

Comment: Related question on the main Meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281760/236563

Comment: Because it's just such an awesome answer, it should be on display for a very long time . . .8->